# Encrypt or hide data in json file (C# WFA)

Tags: c#, json, encryption

(Newbie question, pls be gentle.)

I have written a simple C# Windows Forms Application which uses data stored in json file (about 300 kB). I do not want the data in json file be readable and "copyable" for users, it is meant for displaying in the app only. However, the json file *is* a plain text file, sits together with other program's files and is obviously easily readable and "copyable" for anyone who would have the program itself.
I have understood that json being a plain text file can not be password protected.

Is there any reasonable way to protect the json file so that the users would not have access to its data, only the program would? Which way to go? Encrypt the json file somehow and then have it decrypted by the app itself when run? Or some other approach?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [Encrypting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You can encrypt the file itself, there are many encryption algorithms to use. To be honest this post is to broad/opinionated to even answer. Also worth noting, it will encrypt the data/file, but if the decrypt key exist in the application itself it could be decrypted easily, so it's not fool proof.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander! I was afraid the question is too broad, but you confirmed the general direction that I should look and for now that is enough. Much appreciated!
And I understand that the data can quite easily be decrypted b/c the decrypt key will be in the app itself, but I just want to add a little bit security so that it'd not be in the plain sight; it's not nuclear secrets there so that'd be quite enough, I think.